# Cmdkey with empty password

Tags: powershell, cmd, passwords

I'm trying to start a remote desktop connection to a computer with a user that doesn't have a password, using Powershell. The cmdkey command does not seem to accept an empty password, but asks me for a password with a prompt.

I need to launch the remote desktop from a Powershell-script as it needs to connect to any of several computers at will, so saving the credentials to Remote desktop is not an option.
I have tried using stuff like "", $null, """", "^", ` but none of these work, they are either not a password at all, are the wrong password or just freeze the Powershell-script. The same exact code works just fine for an account that has a password on the same machine.

```bsh
$username=
$IPAddress=
cmdkey /generic:$IPAddress /user:$username
mstsc /v:$IPAddress /admin
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
cmdkey /delete:"LegacyGeneric:target=$IPAddress"
```

The script either asks for the password, or the remote desktop prompts for it, but then accepts just pressing "Ok" with an empty password, or the whole script freezes in some cases. 
It should just connect as the empty password is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Windows will not allow the logon over a network with a blank password. However, there is a registry setting you can do on the target machine that disables this behaviour:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000
```

A 'cleaner' way to set this is by using the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) on the target machine.
Navigate to **Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options** and search for option `Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only`

Double-click this option and check `Disabled`.

From then on, you should be able to remote log on to that computer with a blank password.

---

***Note***: this setting of course provides a security risk.
Read about [Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/accounts-limit-local-account-use-of-blank-passwords-to-console-logon-only)

---

Comment: But why does the remote desktop accept blank passwords if this is the case?

Comment: From my understanding the remote desktop should also be affected by this right?